# increment id using Kotlin SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I want to create a quiz app using Kotlin with SQLite to store quiz questions and answers. Here is what I am expected.

[image]

I want the **COL_ID** increment whenever the quiz is created. I tried autoincrement and change the COL_ID to _ID but not working at all. Any help would appreciated.

```
class DBHelper(context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER) {

    companion object{
        private val DATABASE_VER = 1
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "quizz.db"

        private val TABLE_NAME="Quiz"
        private val COL_ID = "id"
        private val COL_QUESTION="Question"
        private val COL_ANS1 = "Ans1"
        private val COL_ANS2 = "Ans2"
        private val COL_ANS3 = "Ans3"
        private val COL_ANS4 = "Ans4"
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?){ //$COL_ID should start from 1..2..
        val CREATE_TABLE_QUERY:String = ("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_QUESTION TEXT, $COL_ANS1 TEXT, $COL_ANS2 TEXT, $COL_ANS3 TEXT, $COL_ANS4 TEXT) ")
        db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db!!)
    }


    val allQuiz:List<Quiz>
        get(){
            val lstQuiz = ArrayList<Quiz>()
            val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"
            val db = this.writableDatabase
            val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    val quiz = Quiz()
                    quiz.id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID))
                    quiz.question = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_QUESTION))
                    quiz.choice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ANS1))
                    quiz.choice2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ANS2))
                    quiz.choice3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ANS3))
                    quiz.choice4 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ANS4))

                    lstQuiz.add(quiz)
                }while(cursor.moveToNext())
            }
            db.close()
            return lstQuiz
        }

    fun addQuiz(quiz: Quiz){
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(COL_ID, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_QUESTION, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS1, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS2, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS3, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS4, quiz.id)

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
        db.close()
    }

    fun UpdateQuiz(quiz:Quiz):Int{
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(COL_ID, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_QUESTION, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS1, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS2, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS3, quiz.id)
        values.put(COL_ANS4, quiz.id)

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(quiz.id.toString()))
        db.close()
    }
}
```

and here is my add_quiz function in onCreate()

```
db = DBHelper(this)

refreshData()

button_save.setOnClickListener {
   val add_quiz = Quiz {
   //Integet.parseInt //get stuck
   et_question.text.toString(),
   et_choice1.text.toString(),
   et_choice2.text.toString(),
   et_choice3.text.toString(),
   et_choice4.text.toString()
   }
   db.addQuiz(add_quiz)
}
```

Comment: Use autoincrement property to id when creating table.

Comment: If you leave out the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column completely from your insertions (or insert a null for it), sqlite will automatically generate a value for it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_QUESTION TEXT, $COL_ANS1 TEXT, $COL_ANS2 TEXT, $COL_ANS3 TEXT, $COL_ANS4 TEXT)
```

You could set the primary key as `autoincrement`:

```
CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $COL_QUESTION TEXT, $COL_ANS1 TEXT, $COL_ANS2 TEXT, $COL_ANS3 TEXT, $COL_ANS4 TEXT)
```

And don't set the id in addQuiz(). Remove `values.put(COL_ID, quiz.id)` in addQuiz method.

This will create a sequence and get the value from it without you having to manage it.

Another option would be to use the implicitly created `rowid`.

> SQLite implicitly  creates a column named `rowid` and automatically assigns an integer value whenever you insert a new row into the table.

You can find a deeper explanation about this and its benefits in https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Comment: You actually don't need (and often shouldn't use) `AUTOINCREMENT`. See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Yes, there is no need. If you read the whole answer you'll see that the benefits of using the implicitly created `rowid` are also in there. I've just tried to give some explanation on both ways of solving the problem and let the OP to chose the one that he is comfortable with

Comment: A single `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column is just an alias for `rowid`. If you're using it, it's better to be explicit with such an alias, because otherwise things like `VACUUM` can change it.